# How to not show email address when envelope has been sent in DocuSign

Tags: email, docusignapi

Is there a way to not show a sender's address on the email that gets sent to the signer in DocuSign?  Is it possible to just have something like:

From: {picture} Sender's Name

instead of

From: {picture} Sender's Name (senders@email.com)

I tried looking in the features, as well as in branding, but no avail.  Thank you for any responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the contents of emails that DocuSign sends by customizing the "Email Resource File" (an XML file that you can download/upload with the "Branding" section of the DocuSign web console).  This guide contains information about how to do so:  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20System%20Default%20Email%20Formats.pdf.

Note (as specified in the guide) that the ability to modify resource files is a feature that must be enabled for your DocuSign account -- so, if you're not seeing the "Resources" tab within the "Edit Brand" view, then you probably need to contact DocuSign to have it enabled.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer, it seems to be what I was looking for.  Now, I am just trying to get the template/envelope to use that brand.  Do you have to use that in with the API call, or is it set in the dashboard.  I tried setting document brands, but it seems to not be working.

Comment: See "Rules for determining the brandId in an envelope" on page 93 of the DocuSign REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf). (Same logic applies if you're using the SOAP API.)  If you're using the REST API, you can set the **brandId** property in the "Create Envelope" request to specify brand.  If you're using the SOAP API, use the **BrandId** element in the CreateAndSendEnvelope or CreateEnvelope operation to specify brand.